# WPF Bind to selected Radio Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Radiobutton group:

```
 <RadioButton Name="_CreateGraph" GroupName="MapOrGraph" Content="Create Graph" />
 <RadioButton Name="_CreateMap"   GroupName="MapOrGraph" Content="Create Map"   />
```

How do I bind the content of a label to the selected radio button's content?

e.g. the label should say Create Graph or Create Map depending on which radio box is created?

Comment: You can place the RB in listBox (and bind IsChecked To Item.IsSelected) and Bind label To selecteditem\value.

Comment: @lomed, show me code and I accept your answer.  However I do not want to change the look and feel of the radio boxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedValue.Content, ElementName=list}"  />

<ListBox x:Name="list" SelectedIndex="1"  >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
                        <RadioButton GroupName="a" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}  }"  />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem>Create Graph</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Create Map</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

I think you can make it shorter than what I did.

Comment: for some reason I cannot unset the radio boxes and I can also select both of them? I think also that this solution would need a value converter as I cannot see the label changing value?

Comment: You are able to select both RadioButtons, because they're not in group. Add `GroupName="MapOrGraph"` to the RadioButton in the code above and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two RadioButtons, this is a quick & dirty solution:

```
    <Label>
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_CreateGraph}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content, ElementName=_CreateGraph}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_CreateMap}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content, ElementName=_CreateMap}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. Just copy the Label in your XAML and check the names (_CreateGraph, _CreateMap). This should work.